# Programmatically create a new Person having an Internal Login

Tags: sas-metadata

I am trying to programmatically create Users with Internal Accounts as part of a testing system.  The following code can not create an InternalLogin because there is not password hash set at object creation time.

Can a person + internal account be created using metadata_* functions ?

```
data _null_;
  length uri_Person uri_PW uri_IL $256;
  call missing (of uri:);

  rc = metadata_getnobj ("Person?@Name='testbot02'", 1, uri_Person); msg=sysmsg();
  put 'NOTE: Get Person, ' rc= uri_Person= / msg;
  if rc = -4 then do;
  rc = metadata_newobj ('Person', uri_Person, 'testbot02'); msg=sysmsg();
  put 'NOTE: New Person, ' rc= uri_Person= / msg;
  end;

  rc = metadata_setattr (uri_Person, 'DisplayName', 'Test Bot #2'); msg=sysmsg();
  put 'NOTE: SetAttr, ' rc= / msg;

  rc = metadata_newobj ('InternalLogin', uri_IL, 'autobot - IL', 'Foundation', uri_Person, 'InternalLoginInfo'); msg=sysmsg(); 
  put 'NOTE: New InternalLogin, ' rc= / msg;
run;
```

Logs

```
NOTE: Get Person, rc=-4 uri_Person=

NOTE: New Person, rc=0 uri_Person=OMSOBJ:Person\A5OJU4RB.AP0000SX

NOTE: SetAttr, rc=0

NOTE: New InternalLogin, rc=-2
ERROR: AddMetadata of InternalLogin is missing required property PasswordHash.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

The management console and `metabrowse` were used to find what objects might need to be created.

[image]
[image]

Metabrowse

[image]
[image]

Comment: great question!  There is some info here, perhaps you saw it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953244/creating-internal-accounts-in-sas-metadata-server-by-programm-on-sas-base

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Java to create new users.

A `ISecurity_1_1` instance from `MakeISecurityConnection()` on the metadata connection was used to `SetInternalPassword`

Java ended up being a lot more clear coding wise.

```
package sandbox.sas.metadata;

import com.sas.iom.SASIOMDefs.GenericError;
import com.sas.metadata.remote.*;
import com.sas.meta.SASOMI.*;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Richard
 */
public class Main {

    public static final String TESTGROUPNAME = "Automated Test Users";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String metaserver="################";
        String metaport="8561";
        String omrUser="sasadm@saspw";
        String omrPass="##########";

        try 
        {
            MdFactoryImpl metadata = new MdFactoryImpl(false);
            metadata.makeOMRConnection(metaserver,metaport,omrUser,omrPass);

            MdOMIUtil util = metadata.getOMIUtil();
            ISecurity_1_1 security = metadata.getConnection().MakeISecurityConnection();

            MdObjectStore workunit = metadata.createObjectStore();

            String foundationID = util.getFoundationReposID();
            String foundationShortID = foundationID.substring(foundationID.indexOf(".") + 1);

            // Create group for test bot accounts

            List identityGroups = util.getMetadataObjects(foundationID, MetadataObjects.IDENTITYGROUP,  MdOMIUtil.OMI_XMLSELECT,
                    String.format("<XMLSelect search=\"IdentityGroup[@Name='%s']\"/>", TESTGROUPNAME));

            IdentityGroup identityGroup;

            if (identityGroups.isEmpty()) {
                identityGroup = (IdentityGroup) metadata.createComplexMetadataObject (workunit, TESTGROUPNAME, MetadataObjects.IDENTITYGROUP, foundationShortID);
                identityGroup.setDisplayName(TESTGROUPNAME);
                identityGroup.setDesc("Group for Automated Test Users performing concurrent Stored Process execution");
                identityGroup.updateMetadataAll();
            }

            identityGroups = util.getMetadataObjectsSubset(workunit, foundationID, MetadataObjects.IDENTITYGROUP,  MdOMIUtil.OMI_XMLSELECT,
                    String.format("<XMLSelect search=\"IdentityGroup[@Name='%s']\"/>", TESTGROUPNAME));

            identityGroup = (IdentityGroup) identityGroups.get(0);

            // Create (or Update) test bot accounts

            for (int index = 1; index <= 25; index++)
            {
                String token = String.format("%02d", index);

                String personName = String.format("testbot%s", token);
                String password   = String.format("testbot%s%s", token, token);  * simple dynamically generated password for user (for testing scripts only);

                String criteria = String.format("Person[@Name='%s']", personName);
                String xmlSelect = String.format("<XMLSelect search=\"%s\"/>", criteria);

                List persons = util.getMetadataObjectsSubset(workunit, foundationID, MetadataObjects.PERSON, MdOMIUtil.OMI_XMLSELECT | MdOMIUtil.OMI_GET_METADATA | MdOMIUtil.OMI_ALL_SIMPLE, xmlSelect);

                Person person;
                if (persons.size() == 1)
                {
                    person = (Person) persons.get(0);
                    System.out.println(String.format("Have %s %s", person.getName(), person.getDisplayName()));
                }
                else
                {
                    person = (Person) metadata.createComplexMetadataObject (workunit, personName, MetadataObjects.PERSON, foundationShortID);
                    person.setDisplayName(String.format("Test Bot #%s", token));
                    person.setDesc("Internal account for testing purposes");
                    System.out.println(String.format("Make %s, %s (%s)", person.getName(), person.getDisplayName(), person.getDesc()));
                    person.updateMetadataAll();                    
                }

                security.SetInternalPassword(personName, password);

                AssociationList personGroups = person.getIdentityGroups();                
                personGroups.add(identityGroup);
                person.setIdentityGroups(personGroups);
                person.updateMetadataAll();
            }

            workunit.dispose();
            metadata.closeOMRConnection();
            metadata.dispose();
        } 
        catch (GenericError | MdException | RemoteException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: super useful - nice one!